# RestClient throws NullPointerException?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I m getting a NullpointerException but i dont even understand how is it possible.i just copy pasted the part RestTemplate restTemplate = this.restClient.getRestTemplate() from an other class but here i get a NullPointerException ?!

```
@Component
public class ShowRestClient implements ShowService{

@Autowired
private RestClient restClient;
@Override
public List<ShowDto> getShowsByPerformanceID(int perfID)
        throws ServiceException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public List<ShowDto> findAllShows() throws ServiceException {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = this.restClient.getRestTemplate();(!!!!! HERE)
    String url = this.restClient.createServiceUrl("/show/");
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(this.restClient.getHttpHeaders());
    List<ShowDto> shows = null;
    try {
        ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ShowDto>> ref = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ShowDto>>() {};
        ResponseEntity<List<ShowDto>> response = restTemplate.exchange(URI.create(url), HttpMethod.GET, entity, ref);
        shows = response.getBody();
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        throw new ServiceException("Could not retrieve shows: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
return shows;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your RestClient seems to be `null` most likely because `@Autowired` didn't work. I suspect that your component is not an actual Spring Bean, because if it was and then your context creation would fail during app startup. Make sure that you have the package included into package scanning.

Comment: Sorry , i m totally a newbie in Rest ,what you mean with package included into package scanning?
Could you suggest me some step that i can try ?

Comment: @Akin: You are running into Spring config issues, not REST issues. Read up on Spring autowiring and classpath scanning.

Comment: i checked but <context:component-scan base-package="at.ac.tuwien.inso.ticketline.client"/> is totally how it supposed to be...